# Implementing discrete boundary condition for 2D poisson equation using finite difference method

Tags: numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, finite-difference-methods

I'm trying to discretise the following 2D poisson equation:

$-(u_{xx} + u_{yy}) = f(x,y)$  with boundary condition

$u(x,y) = g(x,y)$.

I'm aiming to solve it using the finite difference method, specifically a 5-point stencil which results in a linear system

$\textbf{AU=F}$.

I have managed to determine the A matrix however, I can't seem to figure out how to implement the boundary conditions. Note that the discretised equation in this case is:

$\frac{1}{h^2}(4U_{i,j} - U_{i-1,j} - U_{i,j-1} - U_{i+1,j} - U_{i,j+1}) = f(x_i,y_j)    1 \leq i,j \leq m$

I understand that the boundary conditions allow us to find out the values of any U on the boundaries, but i can't figure out how to implement it in the discretised problem.

many thanks

Comment: You can start by building your system disregarding the boundary conditions an then substitute every line corresponding to a boundary node by identity matrix line (and put the boundary value in the rhs).

Comment: I have managed to do this, however i'm still unsure as to where to go from here. I have seen some resources make a vector "g" which contains the values of the boundary conditios at specific i and j, but i still don't understand where it came from.

Comment: You have to pick a global ordering of the nodes. If you number the nodes left to right and bottom to top, equation k will have nonzero entries $A_{kk}, A_{k,k+1},A_{k,k-1}, A_{k,k+m}, A_{k,k-m}$.

Comment: Then, each equation corresponding to a boundary node needs to be modified in such a way that the solution matches the boundary data. If $k$ is a boundary node, the corresponding equation must be $U_K = g_k$.

Answer (score 1):

If $(x_i,y_j)$ is a boundary node, the equation you presented becomes simply
$$
U_{i,j}=g(x_i,y_i).
$$